# Mailgun + Laravel 10 give me 530 5.7.1 Authentication required when using API

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have a mailgun account with sandbox domain setup.

```
sandbox4400580d984ad30c5.mailgun.org
```

I created sending API key here:

[image: Sending API KEY]

sending API KEY is: aaaaaaaaa-73f745-562c7

I use this API KEY as MAILGUN_SECRET

My laravel .env looks like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox4400580d984ad30c5.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=aaaaaaaaa-73f745-562c7
```

Added and authorized recipient email address - for testing.

And now when I want to send email I got error:

```
530 5.7.1 Authentication required
```

What I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

problem was with wrong .env key

I used

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
```

should be

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
```